# Animation gets messed up when adding multiple animations from Mixamo to the same object

Tags: animation

I'm creating an animated character model for game development, and am using Adobe Mixamo as a source for animations. I auto-rigged my character and imported the animations, and the first one went fine(see video 1). However, after copying the second animation to it, the second animation had the arms crossing and clipping into each other(see video 2). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Videos: https://imgur.com/a/trdI6qQ

Edit: Tested with another animation, went fine. Is it that certain types interfere?

Blend File: [image]

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how to fix this?

Comment: Hello, probably the bones are not rotated the same from an animation to anoter, you could fix that in the Graph Editor, could you please share your file, only keep 2 actions that don't match so that we can try: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ok ill do that thxs

Comment: it won't upload to the site, and it says that the site gets all of the rights to anything i upload

Comment: just keep the armature, 2 actions (if it Mixamo it is free) and use another platform if necessary (like workupload)

Comment: got it one sec adding to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original armature that uses this action probably had its bones rotated slightly differently.

I guess you'll need to correct the bad actions manually: Switch to *Pose* mode, select the shoulder bone, open the *Graph Editor*, hide all the tracks except the X rotation <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, zoom enough in the window so that you can precisely move the curve degree by degree on Y (keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to be precise) until it is correctly rotated, do the same for the upper arm and whatever limb that is not correctly rotated:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked! Thank you!